# Android App not properly refactoring package

Tags: android, refactoring, package, android-manifest

I had to refactor my app package name so I can re-upload my app to the store. (Took it down for a lost keystore). The app package was changed from com.maskyn.marlonjonescodus to com.maskynorig.codusmarlonjones. The Manifest file shows the refactor and so does all of the rest of the code, but when I run the app, the Logcat shows the old package name. It is also shown when I try to upload the app. What is causing this? I have tried cleaning, invalidating, and re-refactoring and nothing has worked. Here is my manifest file:

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Codus"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="sharedcode.turboeditor.application.MyApp"
    >

    <!-- android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.maskynorig.codusmarlonjones.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeEditorDark">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.txt" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.html" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.css" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.js" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.md"/>
            <data android:pathPattern="*.php" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sharedcode.turboeditor.activity.SelectFileActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/open_a_file"
        android:parentActivityName="com.maskynorig.codusmarlonjones.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeBaseLight">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.maskynorig.codusmarlonjones.HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="sharedcode.turboeditor.preferences.ExtraSettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/extra_options"
        android:parentActivityName="com.maskynorig.codusmarlonjones.HomeActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.maskynorig.codusmarlonjones.HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W"
        android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H"
        android:value="598.0dip" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W"
        android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H"
        android:value="598.0dip" />

</application>
```

`

Comment: what do u mean by "upload the app"? where are u uploading it?

Comment: When I try to upload it to Google Play. I pulled my app with the old package name off and tried refactoring so I can upload it.

Comment: here is a screenshot of the logcat: http://imgur.com/KmQeWwF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. While searching, the Gradle still used the old name. Anyone who sees this, check that.